# DELETE requests in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a simple Rails application working just fine in production and development, but the `DELETE` request in production:

Such link:

```
link_to delete_me_path, method: :delete, remote: true
```

- Works fine in development
- Do not on production

I am getting **403** response after clicking the `link` but not sure if the request hit the **server**: Neither the **nginx** nor the **production** log recorded the request.

I don't know if it's coming from my **nginx/passenger** setup or something going on with **jquery** ( No error showing in the `console` )

This is the response I'm getting in **HTML**:

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
 You are not allowed to access the document.</B></FONT>

<!-- default "Access Denied" response (403) -->
</BODY>
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store
Connection:close
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:228
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 20 Jan 2016 16:59:10 GMT
```

## EDIT

Investigating the problem more, I used **CURL**:

```
curl -X DELETE http://example.com/some_path # or any other path
```

returns

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
 You are not allowed to access the document.</B></FONT>

<!-- default "Access Denied" response (403) -->
</BODY>
```

#### Any thoughts ?

Comment: Also check the actual responses sent by the browser - in Chrome you can do this by clicking the Network tab in the inspector. If the browser is sending the request then the next step is checking the logs - you can use `tail -f logs/production.log` from a ssh connection to the server. If the rails server is not receiving the request then check [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/).

Comment: I'm not the one who wrote the 403 response. I pasted the HTML because I found it weird too.

Comment: This html is standard nginx response AFAIK. Are you sure you're hitting the right url?

Comment: Nginx should have two logs: access and error. Check both

Comment: Please check the edit. I used **CURL** to send DELETE requests while monitoring `production.log` | `error.log` |  `access.log` but nothing recorded for any DELETE request. Are there some additional configs to add in order for it to accept DELETE requests.

Comment: In my experience a lot of ISPs don't respect delete request thus causing the issue, please check if the error you are facing is not ISP specific.

Comment: @SiddharthGupta You are just RIGHT !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem occurs when the ISP doesnt support some of the request types, basically the newer one like DELETE, PUT etc.

One pass through is mentioned in this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx). Using VPNs also solves this issue most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

As what @SiddharthGupta pointed, my **ISP** was the source of the problem, I activated a **VPN** and my DELETE requests works fine in production.